# How add group for custom user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-custom-user

I created custom model of user using this official docs [customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/)
But how can add groups and premissions? My django is version 1.9

Answer (score 20):

You can use groups and permissions with your custom user model by using the PermissionsMixin (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions)

Just inherit the PermissionsMixin with your custom user model like so:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

Then you can access it in exactly the same way you would with the default django.contrib.auth User model.

Comment: Thank you. This answer was helpful. Just I want to add one more in here for newbie. If you inherit PermissionsMixin after you already have done migration and migrate with your custom user model, It doesn't create relationship between your custom user model and group or permissions. I was confused for awhile because after inheriting PermissionMixin, I couldn't find tables in db for relationship between user and Group or user and Permission.

Comment: Did you register Group model through `admin.site.register(Group)` ?

Answer (score 11):

#### TL; DR

```
('Group Permissions', {
    'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions', )
})
```

---

#### Detailed Explanation

Add this in admin.py

**app/admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import App


class AppAdminConfig(UserAdmin):
    # ordering, list_display, etc..
    
    fieldsets = (
        # Other fieldsets

        ('Group Permissions', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions', )
        })
    )


admin.site.register(App, AppAdminConfig)
```

If anyone is interested how entire code looks like, see [this](https://pastebin.com/mk4XsEHj).

Comment: Could you details a bit more your answer, in which class this data structure should live?

Comment: Check this. Hope this will clear. If you still unclear, will help you out. Link: https://pastebin.com/mk4XsEHj  Skip to line 36

Comment: Thank you for being responsive. Do you mind to update your answer and just add class nesting and fields name (not the complete code you linked). Goal is to understand in which class and which member this data structure should live. You links is great but you know it breaks. I'll vote up then, I am sure it will help other user! Regards

Comment: Thank you that is a way clearer for new comers !

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @ajinzrathod answer: I applied the solution and got error because I missed some trailing commas. The working code in admin.py is as following:

```py
class UserAdminConfig(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    fieldsets = (
        # Other fieldsets

        ('Group Permissions', {
            'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions', )
        }),
    )
admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdminConfig)
```